# How can I call an async method when a button is clicked and avoid warning messages for message not returning void?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's the code that I have.

The IDE is giving me a warning line under the "async" in the 3rd line, that says "Asynchronous method must not return void"

```
public QHPageViewModel()
{
   DeleteQuizCmd = new Command<string>(async (x) => await DeleteQuizAsync(x));
}  

private async Task DeleteQuizAsync(string quizId)
{
   var canContinue = await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Delete Quiz", "Do you want to delete the results for Quiz " + quizId, "OK", "Cancel");
   if (canContinue == false)
      return;
   App.DB.DeleteQuizHistory(System.Convert.ToInt32(quizId));
   UpdateQuizDetails();
}
```

Is there an issue with the way that this is coded, is there a better way to code this or should I just ignore this message? What are the consequences of ignoring the message?

Comment: Are you sure of this? Your method doesn't return void, it returns `Task`, so this warning makes no sense.

Comment: Instead of `return` use `return Task.Completed`.

Comment: @Vahid the method is marked with `async`, so using `return` is just fine here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It yells at you cause basic XF Commands don't have async capabilities.
If you want warnings to go away, you can write your own AsyncCommand implementing ICommand, or just use the AsyncCommand from stephen cleary: https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async/tree/master/src/Nito.Mvvm.Async

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any warning, and keep the same logic you can also write:

```
if (await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Delete Quiz", "Do you want to delete the results for Quiz " + quizId, "OK", "Cancel")) 
{ 
     App.DB.DeleteQuizHistory(System.Convert.ToInt32(quizId)); 
     UpdateQuizDetails(); 
}
```